# my win7 stopped recognizing Galaxy note2 7100 all the sudden

Tags: windows-7, usb, android, galaxy-s3

I used to plug my device into my PC and I would see in under mycomputer.

This morning it stopped recognizing the device.

I went to ControlPanel\devices and saw: `Unknow Device \ erorr`.

I removed this configuration (deleted it) and plugged out and in again.

Same  `Unknow Device \ erorr`.

[image]

**Update**
I fixed the first issue,

but it's not over yet. I try to access the SD card in my mobile. And it's only doing the progress bar for hours

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of situations like this around the internet.

The solution involves trying and using a new cable and checking if the connectors on the micro usb plug are in the correct position (use a sharp tip knife to slightly lift the connector tongue inside the plug - again, slightly.) .

It is also reported removing all USB devices from your "devices pane" in control panel and rebooting to let Windows reconfigure them solves the problem.

In strange cases, a reboot is needed every time you connect or disconnect your device.

note: this happened to me and it was a defected cable. slightly lifting the tongue inside the plug solved it for good. no more connection problems.

note2: before plugging the device, use the built-in feature to unmount and then mount the sd card.

Answer (score 0):

I went to the DeviceManager, uninstalled the device and plugged out and in again. It worked.

Comment: you might consider upvoting my answer. good you solved it.

Comment: I'll, but it's not over yet. I try to access the SD card in my mobile. And it's only doing the progress bar for hours

Comment: that is where my answer comes in place. i had that same problem.